# Braintree accepting wrong value for account Number

Tags: node.js, braintree

I am using Braintree's Node.js SDK we got an issue regarding account number it accept garbage vale like that 11235***sdfsf**81321 which is wrong. Can anyone help? Braintree validation how to wrok?

```
merchantAccountParams = {
  individual: {
    firstName: "Jane",
    lastName: "Doe",
    email: "jane@14ladders.com",
    phone: "5553334444",
    dateOfBirth: "1981-11-19",
    ssn: "456-45-4567",
    address: {
      streetAddress: "111 Main St",
      locality: "Chicago",
      region: "IL",
      postalCode: "60622"
    }
  },
  business: {
    legalName: "Jane's Ladders",
    dbaName: "Jane's Ladders",
    taxId: "98-7654321",
    address: {
      streetAddress: "111 Main St",
      locality: "Chicago",
      region: "IL",
      postalCode: "60622"
    }
  },
  funding: {
    descriptor: "Blue Ladders",
    destination: braintree.MerchantAccount.FundingDestination.Bank,
    email: "funding@blueladders.com",
    mobilePhone: "5555555555",
    accountNumber: "11235***sdfsf**81321",
    routingNumber: "071101307"
  },
  tosAccepted: true,
  masterMerchantAccountId: "14ladders_marketplace",
  id: "blue_ladders_store"
};

gateway.merchantAccount.create(merchantAccountParams, function (err, result) {
});
```

Answer (score 0):

We can validate the user input from our client side, then we can send a valid value to BrainTree. Account number validation result, we will get only after sending values to BrainTree, they will provide the result in their objects(using BrainTree dll) as a response value.

Please refer [this](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/validation-errors/overview/node) article for more details.